# Repeating Keyframe animation N times

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have key frame animation code like so:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3)
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = Theme.blue10
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = Theme.blue10
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.6, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

However `setAnimationRepeatCount` has been deprecated in iOS13. How would I go about repeating a key frame animation without `setAnimationRepeatCount`?

I looked into `UIViewPropertyAnimator` but there doesn't seem to be an option to repeat these animations `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

Use CABasicAnimation extension like that

```
extension CABasicAnimation {
static let rotation : CABasicAnimation = {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    animation.repeatCount = 3 // change number of count here
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
    animation.duration = 3.0 // change animation duration for single turn
    return animation
 }()
}
```

call it wherever you need it:

```
yuorView.layer.add(CABasicAnimation.rotation, forKey: nil)
```